# Access to Bluettoth SPP in HFP only device (WinCE)

Tags: bluetooth, windows-ce

I would like to gain data over SPP profile into my GPS device. My GPS has Buetooth, but HFP is only accessible profile. It has WinCE that I can use, but I'm not very familiar with this OS.

Is it possible to write WinCE application that will enable/handle BT SPP on device that has HFP profile ?

Comment: I think that it unlikely that the GPS has/has only the Hands-Free Profile. Does it have any audio??  Download my http://32feet.codeplex.com library and compile the SdpBrowser sample either for you PC or for your CE box.  Run it discover the GPS, select it and do SDP->AllRecordsOverL2Cap and SDP->GetServiceNamesOfLast.  How many records does it list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If HFP is the *only* profile available for this device, then I think you answered your own question.
 If you are not the manufacturer of the device, then it is very unlikely that you will be able to use any other profile. One option could be to contact the manufacturer, maybe they will accept to provide you with an OS image that includes the feature you need.